# How to assign dot symbol for the numpad del key in the KDE (X11) permanently?

Tags: kde, keyboard-layout, xkb, setxkbmap

I use the KDE Plasma with X11 on my laptop. And I set up two keyboard layouts in the KDE settings: US English and Russian. I'd like to assign the dot symbol for the numpad Del key. I found the following way to achieve this:

```
setxkbmap -symbols '+kpdl(dotoss)+kpdl(dotoss):2'
```

and this really works... but not for long time. The dot symbol is really assigned after this command, but some time later the default coma symbol from the Russian layout is applied to this key again. I even don't know, what triggers this reset.

I know, that it may be achieved via changing files placed at `/usr/share/X11/xkb/...`, but this approach is not good enough because these files can be overwritten during a system update.

So, my question: how may I assign the dot symbol for the numpad Del key for a non-US layout permanently? Maybe, it's possible to place adjusted `xkb` symbols file(s) somewhere in the home dir in order it to have higher priority over that placed at `/usr/share/X11/xkb` dir?

Comment: You are correct when writing that `/usr/share/X11/xkb/` will be overwritten by further XKeyboardConfig upgrades. Then what about prefering the /etc/X11/xkb directory for your custom changes ?

Comment: @MC68020, no I didn't try to place configs in the `/etc/X11/xkb`. But, it looks like I figured out why the `setxkbmap` command is reset sometimes -- it happens on connecting an external USB-keyboard. As far as I understand, there are the `udev` scripts which reset the xkb map.